# How can I count the number of text fields in a 2-D array?

Tags: arrays, javafx, counter, textfield

In this code, I have created a 2-D array of text fields containing four text fields. I have also put in an `if` statement that checks whether this array is `null`. But I want to count how many text fields in this array?

```
@FXML private TextField f00;
@FXML private TextField f01;
@FXML private TextField f10; 
@FXML private TextField f11;

TextField txt[][] = new TextField [2][2] ; //the array of textfields 

@FXML public void cell() {  
    txt[0][0] = f00;
    txt[0][1] = f01;
    txt[1][0] = f10;
    txt[1][1] = f11;

    for (int i = 0; i<txt.length; i++) {// loop for rows
        for (int j =0; j< txt[0].length; j++) { // loop for columns
            if(!txt.equals(null)) { // if this array isn't null/ empty!
                System.out.println(txt[i][j]); // print what inside this array if the array not null
            }
        System.out.println(" ");
    }
}
```

Comment: I have tried to make a counter loop with while but it doesn't work!

Comment: I wander to ask, in the same code if i  can make or create a counter that counts how many textfields are empty and how many textfields are not empty 

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To count the number of text fields, you could try something like this:

```
int count = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < txt.length; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < txt[i].length; j++) {
        if (txt[i][j] != null) {
            count++
        }
    }
}
System.out.println("Number of text fields: " + count);
```

Comment: Thanks that was exactly what i want 

Answer (score 0):

You check the array itself for null, not the element. Furthermore you use `equals` to check for `null`, which will throw a `NullPointerException` instead of returning `true`, since `null` cannot be dereferenced.

In java 8 you can use `Streams` to do the counting for you:

```
long count = Stream.of(txt).flatMap(Stream::of).filter(Objects::nonNull).count();
```

Comment: like what happened in the first time after i write the code. When i run the program, it throws an exception directly. But thanks for this notice